# how to use shared prefs in background locator to get value

Tags: flutter

hi every one i am using flutter background locator package to fetch user location even the app is close and i use sharedpref to get device id that is stored befor in the background locator callback like this

```
 static void callback(LocationDto locationDto) async {    
    await SharedPrefs().init();
    var id = SharedPrefs().deviceLocationId;
    print('deviceLocationId $id');
    // print('device id ${SharedPrefs().deviceLocationId.toString()}');
    await saveLocation(locationDto.latitude, locationDto.longitude);
    final SendPort send = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('LocatorIsolate');
    send.send(locationDto);
  }
```

but cannot get the sharedpref value and i face with this execption

```
Exception has occurred.
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
```

can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

first initialized your shared preference  in main function or main.dart file then use in it as like this.

```
     Future main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await SharedPref.init();
     runApp(MyApp()); 
}
```

then add it about their instance then use it as like this

```
     static SharedPreferences? _preferences;

    static Future init() async =>
   _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); // create instance of shared preference
```

then use this

```
             _preferences!.setString('username', userName);// set value in shared pref
```

and

```
    _preferences!.getString('username');// get value from shared pref
```

Comment: I have already done that  but it donnot work

Comment: @Mohammadozair i update my answer kindly check it

Comment: i want to use sharedpref in the background_locator package callback it work in other parts of program but not in initcallback of background_locator

Comment: tried but doesn't work!